# Is there an easy way to detect when a DC current flows, then close a path?

Tags: relay, current-measurement

A wire has two states -  20A DC flowing or no current.

Is there a simple device/relay that can let 20A flow through it and close a switch?

[image]

The device must keep a path open when no current flows.
It must close the path when current (DC 20A) flows through it.

I used [this ACS712](https://robu.in/product/acs712-30a-range-current-sensor-module-hall-sensor/) current sensor with a comparator and managed to detect when the current flows but it is too complicated and I feel there must be a more simpler way.

---

- Over current protection is already taken care of externally. The wire has either 20A or none.
- Hysteresis is not needed as we already have a big window (0-20A). If the switch closes when more than 1A flows through the wire, it is good.
- Switch controls a 5V supply and only 10-20 mA current flows.
- We're allowed to break the wire carrying 20A and put the device in series.

---

- By simpler I mean minimum number of parts. Is there a device like a relay or something that lets 20A flow through it and closes a switch? It seems normal relays are controlled by 5V-12V DC voltage. I'm not able to find any relay that lets 20A control current flow through it and closes a switch
- I want a high-side switch to control a 5V 10mA supply. The switch must close when DC 20A current flows through the wire.

Comment: There are many more specs than given which adds complexity. isolated rating, over-current protection, threshold, hysteresis, heat rise, switch rating for V,I

Comment: Please show your solution in detail and tell us in what way you want it to be *"simpler"*.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I'll try to answer few... over current protection is already taken care of. The wire has either 20A or none. hysteresis is not needed as we already have a big window (0-20A). Switch is 5V and only mA flows.

Comment: I'll update above in the question. Thank you for pointing it out @TonyStewartEE75

Comment: @devnull by simpler i mean minimum number of parts. is there a device like relay or something that lets 20A flow through it and close a switch? It seems normal relays are controlled by 5V-12V dc voltage. I'm not able to find any relay that lets 20A control current flow through it and close a switch..

Comment: @devnull basically I want a high-side switch to control 5V 10mA supply. The switch must close when dc 20A current flows through the wire..

Comment: How many turns of AWG 14 magnet wire @ 20A is needed to switch a Reed switch?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 interesting, the wire is AWG 13. I'm not familiar with Reed switches, let me do some reading and get back..

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Perhaps i can coil up the same wire(3-4 turns) around a reed switch and make it work ? you're a lifesaver! (the switch will close when current flowing creates enough magnetic field). This setup seems like a reed switch sitting inside a solenoid...

Comment: Depends on your magnetic switch and coil orientation and turns

Comment: Understood.. I'll do the math thanks again for the brilliant idea! @TonyStewartEE75 you're awesome!!

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 looks 20A current carrying wire produces 800 uT at a distance 5mm. This may be good enough to close a reed switch. I'll order one and see... Thanks!   https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/magnetic-field-of-straight-current-carrying-wire

Comment: The expensive glass power reed switches are 50 to 150 A-turns. It's hard to guess what your insulation thickness is and reed sensitivity.  Magnetic wire over Teflon tape to stripped wire might be the smallest gap,d  if you can wrap that tight on a former then slip over the glass without breaking it and bond with adhesive. But there may be cheaper ways for mass production perhaps.

Comment: Just buy an off-the-shelf [Current Sense Relay](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08S6RTXXQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1). Ofc you should choose a well-made device from a reliable manufacturer rather than from the online lree-market ;).

Comment: *flee-market ...

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I bought 14mm reed switch and it closed with out any turns at 20A! Thank you so so much! I'm super excited as I can now replace the entire ACS712 current sensor and comparator PCB with just a single reed switch. This also makes quiescent current of my circuit 0! Here is a pic of my work if interested... With 6 turns, I could make the switch close at just 1.5A: https://prnt.sc/wg550LUEOUu3

Comment: Btw I'm using 13AWG wire with PTFE insulation so the thickness of insulation is less than 1mm.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can wind 4-5 turns of the wire around a glass body reed contact. This contact will close at 20A.

I just tried reed contact ORD324-1015. One singe turn is enough to turn on at around 8A.

*Update: sharing the picture to document the solution to the original problem*

[image]

Comment: I used this exact setup as part of the deactivation circuit for a car alarm.  Wrapped a couple turns of the cigarette lighter lead around a reed relay and used that contact to extend the entry delay.  Push the lighter in and you get an extra 30 seconds.

Comment: This worked like a charm without any turns at 20A! With 6 turns, my 14mm reed switch is closing at as low as 1.5A current.  Thank you so much! you all are awesome!!

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wg550LUEOUu3

Comment: @across Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

I think the current sensor is as simple as its going to get. You can then put the output signal into a comparator (or opamp, like LM741, acting as comparator). The other input of the comparator is coming from a potentiometer voltage divider where you can set the threshold between 0 and 5V, the output of the comparator then goes to a transistor to drive a relay coil.
Modules like this exist already, but you have specific requirements that I don't think fit any of them, so you'll have to build your own module like this.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000089725866.html

Comment: Ohk thank you so there are no simple relay/electromagnet like devices that just close a switch when 20A current flows. I'm already doing your idea:  ACS712 current sensor -  LM358 opamp - BC548 bjt. It's working fine but the current sensor also requires power supply and comparator requires a pot and BC548 requires two biasing resistors.  I ended up with soldering 7 components on a small pcb board just for detecting current! Thanks again!

Comment: A Hall effect sensor (the magnet sensing switching kind) would do, if a logic level rather than switch closure output is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple device/relay that can let 20A flow through it and close a switch?

A range of current relays, meant for refrigerator / freezer applications, are available.

Typical operating currents in the range are as shown.

[image]

The one that suits your application may be selected from the range.